# tensorflow doesn't use GPU even it's detecting it

Tags: python, gpu

while executing my tensorflow 1.15 python code. i noticed that it's detection my GPU :

```
2021-11-09 13:52:56.890952: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_100.dll
2021-11-09 13:52:56.891239: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_100.dll
2021-11-09 13:52:56.891526: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_100.dll
2021-11-09 13:52:56.891841: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_100.dll
2021-11-09 13:52:56.892128: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_100.dll
2021-11-09 13:52:56.892418: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_100.dll
2021-11-09 13:52:56.892707: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2021-11-09 13:52:56.893042: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1746] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-11-09 13:53:04.263485: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1159] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-11-09 13:53:04.263803: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1165]      0 
2021-11-09 13:53:04.263989: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1178] 0:   N 
2021-11-09 13:53:04.293081: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1304] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6311 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
2021-11-09 14:08:32.294865: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER major: 7 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.68
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
```

but when I go to the task manager I notice that the GPU is not used while execution :

My task manager while executing of the code:

[image]

how to use the GPU more than CPU while executing my code in order th accelerate the exe because it's taking so much time ??

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your CUDA graph in that picture says 89% and you are using 6GB of GPU RAM.

[image]

It definitely is using the GPU, the other graphs are apparently showing low figures because you are not doing 3D stuff.

If you need it to go faster now then you will likely need a better GPU.

Comment: Thank you you for your answer, But as it's saying the use of GPU is only 5 % i wanted it to use it more than that.

Comment: Tensorflow is using 89%of the shader cores on your GPU. The rest of the GPU being idle is because your program doesn't need to use those parts and as a result the rest of your GPU looks idle. The 5% does not mean that your GPU is idle, just that parts your program cannot use are idle.

Comment: @BayaLina that 5% appears to correlate with the "3D" graph. Your program is not doing "3D" work, it is doing CUDA work and so the "total" graph is misleading. You only need to care about the CUDA graph.

Comment: I'm grateful for your answer.